# Kernel of an operator

Tags: integration, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

can you help me to solve this exercice?
Show that the kernel of the operator $M:L^2((-1,1))\to L^2((-1,1))$ has infinite dimension.
The operator is: $$ M[f](x):= \int_{(-1,1)} \sin(xy)f(y)\,\,\,dy. $$

Hint. Denote with P the operator that $f(x)\to f(-x)$, we have $MP[f]=PM[f]$. Observe how M operates with even functions.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is an even function, then $M(f) = 0.$ QED

Comment: very simple, thanks!         :)